(Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
I have a powershell script that should do the Windows updates using the PSwindowsUpdate module but when I run it I get an Access Denied error. (HRESULT exception: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) while I have administrator rights
$Window.FindName("WUforce").add_click({
    $info = $Window.FindName('info')
    $computer = $Window.FindName('PCWU').Text
    $info.Text = "Forcing updates on $computer..."
    
    try {
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force -SkipPublisherCheck
            Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
            Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm
        }
        
        $info.Text = "Windows updates have been installed and the computer may have restarted."
    } catch {
        $info.Text = "Error: $_"
    } finally {
        if ($session) { Remove-PSSession -Session $session }
    }
})

I tried to modify the code by putting in a scriptblock of an invoke-command (Invoke-Command -ComputerName D23-0495 -ScriptBlock {Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot}) or simply with the line (Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot -ComputerName D23-0495) but nothing works

Are all the machines in the same domain?  You need Admin on both local and remote machines.  Not al Admin are the same.  You may only have local admin and not network admin.

all machines are in the same domain

Are machines using Windows Credentials or OAUTH2?

Windows Credentials

Read following : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/problems-with-powershell-scripts-and-credential/df59d365-5090-4b81-8714-2102bf3c8cae
